# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'outs' referenced before assignment - durnig training the model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm keras beginner

```
Epoch 9/100
99/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4229 - acc: 0.8649Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve
100/100 [==============================] - 72s - loss: 0.4222 - acc: 0.8650 - val_loss: 1.2091 - val_acc: 0.5000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Train.py", line 382, in <module>
train(args)
File "Train.py", line 351, in train
scores = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, workers=5, steps = None)
File "/home/Grace/kerasenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/Grace/kerasenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1991, in evaluate_generator
if not isinstance(outs, list):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'outs' referenced before assignment
```

my code is here.

```
    scores = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, workers=5, steps = None)

    history_ft = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_steps = 3,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks = [tensorboard, checkpointer, EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=5)],
    class_weight = 'auto',
    workers = 5,
    use_multiprocessing = True)
```

## parameter

- steps_per_epoch = 100
- nb_epoch =100
- Batch Size: 8

  - Found 1134 images belonging to 4 classes.(Train set)
  - Found 174 images belonging to 4 classes.(validation set)
- my version of keras 2.0.6,
- tensorflow: 1.3.0

Somebody knows why? Thanks

Comment: what is validation_generator in this code? Why are you setting steps to None in the evaluate_generator call?

Comment: validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_path,
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        seed=13,
#         subset='validation'
    )

Comment: I don't know the step size, so just set as None.

Comment: Of course you know it, its the number of validation samples dividided by the batch size. You have to set this parameter.

Comment: "local variable 'outs' referenced before assignment" What is 'outs'?